# Can I create Custom Device Picker for iOS CastSDK 4.5.0

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast-sdk

In Swift Google Cast SDK 4.5.0 can I create Custom Device picker ?

Previously while using `'3.4.0'` I was able to do it using GCKDeviceScanner. As for now for 4.5.0 device scanning is done automatically. So I want to know if I still can create a custom device picker cause my application design is different.

To be more specific Screenshot is attached of the screen I want to customize.

[image]

i have gone through all the documentation but couldn't find anything

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So Finally I found a solution. Instead of using `GCKCastButton` I used custom Cast Button or we just need to give custom `selector` to `GCKCastButton`.
And for Discovering Devices and showing those in your custom view, We can use `GCKDiscoverManager` like this

```
let gckCastOptions = GCKCastOptions(receiverApplicationID: kGoogleCastAppReceiverId)
    GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWithOptions(gckCastOptions)
    GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    self.discoveryManager = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().discoveryManager
    self.discoveryManager!.addListener(self)
    self.discoveryManager!.passiveScan = true
    self.discoveryManager!.startDiscovery()
```

And then the Listener method

```
func didStartDiscoveryForDeviceCategory(deviceCategory: String) {
    print("GCKDiscoveryManagerListener: \(deviceCategory)")

    print("FOUND: \(self.discoveryManager!.hasDiscoveredDevices)")
}
```

I hope this can help someone struggling to find solution to the problem I faced.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_discovery_manager

Comment: In order to get the actual device, you also need to implement didInsert(_ device: GCKDevice, at index: UInt) from GCKDiscoveryManagerListener